# iOS custom keyboard height increases on every switch

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I have a frustrating issue I have no idea how to solve

When working on a custom keyboard I discovered that on a particular screen - Apple Mail app Reply - custom keyboard gets an increase in height on every keyboard switch.

I narrowed it down to actually zero code

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

Almost everywhere it looks 'normally', that is, takes up the same size as the standard keyboard - e.g. the Messages app

[image]

But the Reply screen in the Apple Mail (and maybe few other places) after a few keyboard switches looks like this

[image]

What could be causing it?

FWIW the UIKit code that I tried a while ago has only a minimal issue of flashing, then instantly resizing to normal. My current production code is SwiftUI, and it's going to be a pain to rewrite everything back and even then it can return at any point because the zero code version also has this.

**EDIT**

Also tried the manual constraint path. It made no difference.

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let constr = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self.view!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 66)
        constr.priority = .defaultHigh
        view.addConstraint(constr)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the code you've shown is that you are not setting the input view's height! See (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469514/ios-custom-keyboard-increase-uiinputviewcontroller-height for how to control the height.

Comment: @matt I tried that, it made no difference unfortunately. The manual constraints only work when `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` if off, but then the rest of the area is just blank grey.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me (as a workaround) was wrapping my SwiftUI with KeyboardKit. No idea still what to do with UiKit.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, and show some code? Facing the same problem.

Comment: @Tanvirgeek https://github.com/duzenko/ios-keyboard but I suspect it's not a good example to follow